# c# wpf window instance of other window

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new c# and wpf. Currently I'm converting our old vb6 code to c#.
How can i convert this piece of code to c#?

NOTE: 
I have multiple Forms to cater different payments w/c have different object and control in it.
   1. dlgPaymentCash
   2. dlgCard
   3. dlgCheck

```
Dim dlgpayment As Form

Select Case paymentType
 Case "CASH": Set dlgpayment = New dlgPaymentCash
 Case "CARD": Set dlgpayment = New dlgCard
 Case "CHECK": Set dlgpayment = New dlgPaymentCheck
End Select
```

Is this possible in c# and what is the best way?

Comment: WPF is a different UI framework than WinForms!. I would recommend that you stay with WinForms if you are just converting between .NET languages. At least if you haven't been told otherwise.

Comment: This is especially true if you are coming from Visual Basic 6 (which is not a .NET language!). Switching to .NET **and** WPF will be a very difficult task unless you are completely rewriting your application (which requires you to know the languages *first*, and then start with fresh architecture).

Comment: @poke: true, I missed that VB6 is rather old.

Answer (score 1):

It's been some time since I have programmed VB, but I guess you are on the right track with this code. Be aware that you probably will have to handle the default case (null) if paymentType might become something else than the existing choices.

```
Form dlgPayment = null;

switch (paymentType)
{
    case "CASH": dlgpayment = new dlgPaymentCash();
        break;
    case "CARD": dlgpayment = new dlgCard();
        break;
    case "CHECK": dlgpayment = new dlgPaymentCheck();
        break;
}
```

Even if VB6 is not .NET, anything is possible in C# also. There might be some additional effort however.

Comment: Thanks oliver, but when i do that, i cannot access the control of the original dlgPaymentCash.  dlgPayment.tbAmountDue.Text = 0;  
Error CS1061 'Window' does not contain a definition for 'tbAmountDue' and no extension method 'tbAmountDue' accepting a first argument of type 'Window' could be found

Comment: Window is a class of WPF, not of WinForms. In your VB6 code dlgpayment is declared as a Form, not a Window. Do you want to use WinForms and WPF side-by-side? That wouldn't be a good idea for a beginner, I guess. I am afraid we need a little more context to help you.